Meaning of フラグを立てる in this context
I don't get what she meant by「とか言ってもう何人かとフラグ立ててたりして?」in this scene. I think she is asking to be in relationship with many people...?


I assume you've looked up what フラグ means in general as slang:

What is 漕ぎに来てくれるフラグ in English?

"Raising a flag" does not mean a romantic relationship has been established at this point. "Raising a flag with someone" only suggests that there's a high chance of future events occurring that will deepen the relationship with that particular character. When she says "You may have already raised flags for several people", it means he may be viewed as a potential romantic partner by several girls. This type of フラグ is specifically called 恋愛フラグ, and it's a piece of slang widely used even by non-gamers.
